# Show/hide div element according to screen size, but allow that to be reversed by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I have a site where I want to be able to show or hide a div based on both user input (clicking/tapping a button) and screen size:

a) If the screen width is greater than a certain size, show the div but allow the user to hide it.

b) If the screen with is less than a certain size, hide the div but allow the user to reveal it.

What I'm struggling with is getting these two requirements to interact properly.

I'm using Foundation 5 and jQuery, so both parts of this are possible - Foundation's "show-for-foo-up" handles initial visibility, and there are numerous jQuery functions that allow a div to be toggled between visible and hidden. But what I can't seem to do is find a way to allow a user click to reveal a div that has initially been hidden by Foundation's media query, or a way to do a pure jQuery toggle (ignoring Foundation) that sets the initial visibility according to screen size.

What makes this more complex is that the div contains a form. So I can't simply repeat it in two different divs and toggle between them, as doing that would either mean duplicate element ids or two different forms, both of which aren't possible in this scenario.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm open to either a jQuery solution, a Foundation solution or a pure javascript solution, just so long as it works!

Comment: Just add a classes to the element via jQuery (one to show the element despite what the MQs say, one to hide it despite what the MQs say) - and then just write some rules in your stylesheet, that based on this class have a higher _specificity_ than the rules inside your MQs …?

Comment: Actually, it's just occurred to me (ten minutes after posting the question, and a few hours after scratching my head over it!) that one way of doing it is simply to use the jQuery function to change the class of the div. So "show-for-medium-up" becomes "hide-for-medium-up" on click and back again. I will experiment and see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CBroe's comment put me on the right track and my assumption thereafter was correct. All it needs is to use jQuery to alter the class of the div to add or remove the class which uses a media query. Dunno why I didn't think of this before, really.